# Hibernate row value constructor

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hql

Does anyone know how to translate the where condition of this HQL fragment to CriteriaQuery?

```
from Cat as cat
where not ( cat.name, cat.color ) in (
    select cat.name, cat.color from DomesticCat cat
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class, "c");

DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DomesticCat.class, "dc");
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("dc.name"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("dc.color"));
subquery.setProjection(projectionList);

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertiesNotIn(new String[] { "c.name", "c.color" }, subquery));
```